# Are unused functions optimized out of WebGL shaders?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

From what I gather unused attributes/uniforms are ignored by the compiler. Does the same happen with unused functions?

I'm writing a WebGL wrapper in JS and was thinking of automatically adding a couple of often used functions (1/2/3d Perlin noise, pseudo-random, quaternion->matrix, etc) to every shader before compiling it. Just wanted to make sure it won't cause any performance issues.

Comment: It depends on the compiler whether or not those function or attributes/uniformes are optimised out. But I would say that you could assume that they will always be optimised out. Anyway even if not it would not really be a performance but more a memory problem.

Comment: But you probably want to take a look at [glslify](https://github.com/stackgl/glslify)

Comment: Thank you, that looks interesting.

Comment: Functions are often inlined so not calling them would optimise them out

Comment: Functions are alwaws inlined so not calling them will optimise them out

Comment: There is a limit to the size of the shader that you can compile, and it's not that big so adding too much will break the shader.  You can  create a simple linker that you run over the shader source before you compile. Anything in the shader that is not declared should thus be in the link file and just add what is needed. A very useful tool if you like to write shaders.

Comment: @pleup: "*Functions are alwaws inlined*" This is not true.

Comment: @Blindman67 yeah, I already parse the shader source in order to make a list of uniforms/attributes and such. I could also search for function calls and add what is necessary. Should've thought about it the first thing. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @nicol-bolas Have you ever seen a compiler generate bytecode containig subroutine definition and subroutine call instructions  with a glsl 1.00 profile (it's a real question). For what i've tested, most recent hardware/driver don't even support basic branching with this profile.

Comment: @pleup: "*Have you ever seen a compiler generate bytecode containig subroutine definition and subroutine call instructions with a glsl 1.00 profile (it's a real question).*" Making the claim that functions are "always inlined" requires more than simply seeing lots of compilers inlining functions. You have to have direct evidence that the compiler will *never* not inline a function, no matter how many times it gets called, in what dynamic circumstances, or whatever.